# 有认真地考虑过 or 有认真的考虑过?

Tags: syntax, past-tense

I've come across the following sentence:

> 我和我的家人其实有很认真地考虑过要不要买一个空调。
> Wǒ hé wǒ de jiārén qíshí yǒu hěn rènzhēn de kǎolǜ guo yào bu yao mǎi yíge kōngtiáo.

If 考虑 is a main verb, 有 ends up being an auxiliary, which would make the sentence nonstandard.

To avoid this interpretation, one could paraphrase it as follows:
我和我的家人其实有过很认真的考虑要不要买一个空调。

Is this paraphrase grammatical?

Even if only marginally grammatical, does it intuitively preserve the meaning of the original sentence?

If the answer to this last question is 'yes', shouldn't then the spelling of the original sentence use 很认真的考虑 instead of 很认真地考虑 ?

EDIT: This question is about the syntactic relation between 有 and 考虑. My suggestion that the later might be a deverbal noun is just that, a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

[的] is a [adjectival] marker that is always followed by a [noun]

[地] is a [adverbial] marker that is always followed by a [verb]

Since 考虑 is a verb, "有认真地考虑过" is the correct answer.

The reason you often see sentences like "有认真的考虑过" with 的 acting like 地 is that both 的 and 地 are pronounced 'de' and many people use them interchangeably when /de/ functioning as an adverbial marker. (when /de/ is functioning as an adjectival marker, people do know they can't replace 的 with 地)

Too many people make the same mistake for anyone to correct every instance, now it is almost an acceptable usage of 的 as a replacement of 地 by popular consent

(*It goes like this: "ok. you are one of those people who use 的 when it should be 地. Instead of arguing with you, I would pretend 的 here also means 地*")

The difference between 的 and 地

- 他**认真地**考虑 = he **seriously** consider
- 一個**认真的**考虑 = a **serious** consideration
- 很认真的考虑 = very serious consideration
- 很认真地考虑 = very seriously consider

Note:

using 的/de/ instead of 得/dé/ for a [degree particle] is another common mistake that almost is accepted as legitimate

e.g. 打得十分好 --> 打的十分好; 跑得很快 --> 跑的很快

Comment: You imply there's nothing in the sentence I cited to make 考虑 a deverbal noun. Then, I also suppose that you couldn't put an object after such a noun, as in "一些认真的考虑要不要买一个空调". Instead, then, you would have to premodify the noun using a preposition such as 至于 or 关于.

Comment: This leaves me with my initial problem. I've read Chinese linguists do not consider 有 as an auxiliary; so, it seems we have the phrase 很认真的考虑要不要买一个空调 functioning like an object of 有 yet retaining its internal structure as a verb phrase.

Comment: In my last comment, I of course meant to write (or rather paste) 很认真地考虑要不要买一个空调. My question has never been about the usage of 地 to form an adverb. This is taken for granted.

Comment: @PapaSmurf Although 有+verb is non-standard in Mandarin, it is common in certain dialects, and this usage has bleed into mainstream Chinese. It's rather analogous to present/past perfect tense in English.

Answer (score 0):

1. 我和我的家人其实有很认真地考虑过要不要买一个空调。

For 2. see note below:

2. 我和我的家人其实很认真的考虑过要不要买一个空调。

> 1956 年制定的《暂拟汉语教学语法系统》主张的“的”“地”分用。其后渐渐推广开来。但是1984
> 年替代“暂拟系统”的《中学教学语法系统提要》又主张“的” “地”合用。

Comment: “的” “地”合用 祇限以 "的" 替代 "地" 作副詞用，卻不容許以 "地" 替代 "的" 作形容詞用, 所以合用之說其實不能成立

Answer (score 0):

> 我和我的家人其实有很认真地考虑过要不要买一个空调。

I wouls pase the sentence as:

我和我的家人(I and my family)其实(actually)有(have ever)很认真地(very seriously)考虑过(considered)要不要(whether)买(to buy)一个空调(an air conditioning).

- I and my family actually have ever very seriously considered whether to buy an air conditioning.

Two alternate sentences:

我和我的家人(I and my family)很认真地(very seriously)考虑(consider)要不要(whether)买(to buy)一个空调(an air conditioning).

- I and my family very seriously consider whether to buy an air conditioning.

我和我的家人(I and my family)认真的(serious)考虑(consider)要不要(whether)买(to buy)一个空调(an air conditioning).

- I and my family serious consider whether to buy an air conditioning.