# using 的 between adverb and adjective

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, 的 is used between an adjective and a noun.
Like 漂亮的姑娘

But I have seen many examples that 的 is used between an adverb and an adjective.

Here are the examples,

1. 生活在中国不同地方的人吃的食物也非常的不一样。
2. 特别的聪明
3. 他觉得非常的舒服。
4. 这两个女孩儿非常的热情。
5. 他工作非常的努力。

Is this grammatically correct? I haven't seen this in grammar books. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to my old post [有认真地考虑过 or 有认真的考虑过?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/52770/%e6%9c%89%e8%ae%a4%e7%9c%9f%e5%9c%b0%e8%80%83%e8%99%91%e8%bf%87-or-%e6%9c%89%e8%ae%a4%e7%9c%9f%e7%9a%84%e8%80%83%e8%99%91%e8%bf%87/52772#52772)

> [的] is a [adjectival] marker that is always followed by a [noun]

> [地] is a [adverbial] marker that is always followed by a [verb] or an [adjective]

> The reason you often see 的 acting like 地 is that both 的 and 地 are pronounced 'de' and many people use them interchangeably. Now it is almost an acceptable usage of 的 as a replacement for 地 by popular consent

There is a drawback because some adjectives are the same words when used as a noun, then the adverb with 的 instead of 地 would become an adjective

Example:

特别的(adv)聪明(adj) = specially intelligent

特别的(adj)聪明(n) =special intelligence

非常的(adv)热情(adj) = unusually passionate

非常的(adj)热情(n) = unusual passion

Answer (score 0):

In the 前言 from 名词和动词， 沈家煊 著

> 根本书的观点一致， 行文中虚字“的”（的/地）除例句和引文一律写作“的”，免去有时候难以选择的烦恼， 而不致影响文意的理解。
>
> 作者 2014年10月21日写于北京寓所

Many Chinese linguists are opposed to the arrogant assumption that Chinese must conform with Western ideas about language and grammar.

If a noun is used as an adjective, or an adjective is used as a noun, what is it actually? 它的性质变不变吗？

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned elsewhere, it is inappropiate trying to classify and study Chinese using a set of Western/English lingustic rules/grammar.